# Extracting Patterns with Python reg exp

Tags: python, regex

Sample String 1:

```
::SCOPE:Confidentiality:SCOPE:Access Control:SCOPE:AuthorizationTECHNICAL IMPACT:Gain Privileges::
```

Sample String 2:

```
::SCOPE:ConfidentialityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Read Data::
```

Sample String 3:

```
::SCOPE:AvailabilityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Unreliable Execution::SCOPE:Confidentiality:SCOPE:Integrity:SCOPE:AvailabilityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Execute Unauthorized Commands:NOTE:Confidentiality Integrity Availability Execute Unauthorized Commands Run Arbitrary Code::SCOPE:ConfidentialityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Read Data::SCOPE:IntegrityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Modify Data::SCOPE:Confidentiality:SCOPE:Access Control:SCOPE:AuthorizationTECHNICAL IMPACT:Gain Privileges::
```

For Sample String 1, I would want to extract -

```
Confidentiality
Access Control
Authorization
Gain Privileges
```

For Sample String 2, I would want to extract -

```
Confidentiality
Read Data
```

For sample string 3: I would want to extract -

```
1 - 
Availability
Unreliable Execution
```

2- 
Confidentiality
Integrity
Availability
Execute Unauthorized Commands

3- 
Confidentiality
Read Data

4- 
Integrity
Modify Data

5- 
Confidentiality
Access Control
Authorization
Gain Privileges

I started to write a simple reg exp -

```
::SCOPE:([\w\s]+)TECHNICAL IMPACT:([\w\s]+)
```

that would extract String 2.

I then then wrote reg exp -

```
::SCOPE:([\w\s]+):SCOPE:([\w\s]+):SCOPE:([\w\s]+)TECHNICAL IMPACT:([\w\s]+)
```

that would extract String 3.

However, these expression are static.

The general that I see is - ::SCOPE:**[part 1 to extract]** TECHNICAL IMPACT:**[part 2 to extract]**
This general pattern may in multiple part of the a given string, but **[part 1 to extract]** is variable with what is to be extracted.

How can I find this general pattern in the string as many times then extract   from each one using reg exp?

Comment: Something like this ? https://regex101.com/r/YiBFlp/1

Comment: I wonder whether it is not a too complex task for regex alone...

Comment: Thank you for your response @Jan, I just want to say that I edited the question.  I am first looking for this general pattern - ::SCOPE:[part 1 to extract] TECHNICAL IMPACT:[part 2 to extract] . The solution shows :NOTE:Confidentiality Integrity Availability Execute Unauthorized Commands Run Arbitrary Code from string 3 being extracted. So, I just want to find all ::SCOPE:[part 1 to extract] TECHNICAL IMPACT:[part 2 to extract] then do extract both part 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

The only trick needed is to grab all words but ignore consecutive runs of capitals.

```
print (re.findall(r'[A-Z]?[a-z]+(?: [A-Z]?[a-z]+)*', text))
```

It returns the following for your test cases:

1. ['Confidentiality', 'Access Control', 'Authorization', 'Gain Privileges']
2. ['Confidentiality', 'Read Data']
3. ['Availability', 'Unreliable Execution', 'Confidentiality', 'Integrity', 'Availability', 'Execute Unauthorized Commands', 'Confidentiality Integrity Availability Execute Unauthorized Commands Run Arbitrary Code', 'Confidentiality', 'Read Data', 'Integrity', 'Modify Data', 'Confidentiality', 'Access Control', 'Authorization', 'Gain Privileges']

Comment: I want to extract ::SCOPE:**[part 1 to extract]** TECHNICAL IMPACT:**[part 2 to extract]  **, the current solution will also extract :NOTE:Confidentiality Integrity Availability Execute Unauthorized Commands Run Arbitrary Code from string 3. I am looking for this specific pattern first - ::SCOPE:**[part 1 to extract]** TECHNICAL IMPACT:**[part 2 to extract] ** then extract from part 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

I would use re.split for that task following way:

```
import re
s1 = '::SCOPE:Confidentiality:SCOPE:Access Control:SCOPE:AuthorizationTECHNICAL IMPACT:Gain Privileges::'
s2 = '::SCOPE:ConfidentialityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Read Data::'
s3 = '::SCOPE:AvailabilityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Unreliable Execution::SCOPE:Confidentiality:SCOPE:Integrity:SCOPE:AvailabilityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Execute Unauthorized Commands:NOTE:Confidentiality Integrity Availability Execute Unauthorized Commands Run Arbitrary Code::SCOPE:ConfidentialityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Read Data::SCOPE:IntegrityTECHNICAL IMPACT:Modify Data::SCOPE:Confidentiality:SCOPE:Access Control:SCOPE:AuthorizationTECHNICAL IMPACT:Gain Privileges::'
ext1 = [i for i in re.split(r'[:A-Z ]*:', s1) if i]
ext2 = [i for i in re.split(r'[:A-Z ]*:', s2) if i]
ext3 = [i for i in re.split(r'[:A-Z ]*:', s3) if i]
```

Then:

- ext1 is `['Confidentiality', 'Access Control', 'Authorization', 'Gain
  Privileges']`
- ext2 is `['Confidentiality', 'Read Data']`
- ext3 is       `['Availability', 'Unreliable Execution',
  'Confidentiality',       'Integrity', 'Availability', 'Execute
  Unauthorized Commands',       'Confidentiality Integrity Availability
  Execute Unauthorized Commands    Run Arbitrary Code',
  'Confidentiality', 'Read Data', 'Integrity',       'Modify Data',
  'Confidentiality', 'Access Control', 'Authorization',     'Gain
  Privileges']`

I was simply looking for substrings consisting of `:`, spaces and uppercase letters and ending with `:` to split at, then removed empty `str`s from `list`s produced by `re.split`s